# UIAlertView easy way to tell if cancel button is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uialertview

I know I've done this before but I just can't figure it out again.

What is the method I would use to see if a cancel button was pressed. I don't want to do it based on the button index. There is a way to do it, something like:

```
[alertView isCancelIndex:index];
```

Anyone know?

Comment: That kind of questions are easily solved by the documentation. You'd also be saving a lot of time. It's as easy as googling for UIAlertView class reference, clicking on Apple's link, and scrolling down a little to the list of properties and methods.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The UIAlertView has a property of cancel button index

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger cancelButtonIndex
```

Usage

```
[alertView cancelButtonIndex]
```

Answer (score 32):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

  if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
    NSLog(@"The cancel button was clicked for alertView");
  }
// else do your stuff for the rest of the buttons (firstOtherButtonIndex, secondOtherButtonIndex, etc)
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In the delegate of UIAlertView is the method

> (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
>   clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

And then:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSInteger cancelIndex = [alertView cancelButtonIndex];
    if (cancelIndex != -1 && cancelIndex == buttonIndex)
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP specifically said not using that method

Comment: I think the OP meant that he didn't want to hard-code the index.  (To the extent that he knew what he meant.)